Need help identifying tiny 2 pin connector
I managed to break on side’s retaining tabs on this tiny male 2 pin connector while rebuilding my Dyson V-10. Searched all over trying to find its likeness. Any help would be appreciated.
enter image description here



That's a "parallel mate" wire-to-board connector. It could be one of these (my Identiconn site). But to me it looks like this one: JST DF57

Plug housing: DF57-2S-1.2C
Crimp contact: DF57-2830SCF


{Source: Digikey}
